# How to do hover to focus AND allow keyboard switching via ctrl tab etc?

Tags: gnome, window

You use gnome tweaks to turn on hover to focus. But then you can not also use keyboard shortcuts to change between windows AND type in the other windows. You have to then use the mouse to hover over the window you changed to using the keyboard.

Comment: This is not a question. In addition, it's not true. I use focus-follows-mouse, and can happily ALT+Tab without moving my mouse, and type in a different window. Works fine.

Comment: @popey what do you mean it's not true? I am living it. There is *some* setting that has changed. I am on 22.10 ... I think I saw a post where some behaviour had changed in recent updates.

Also might be some things change on multi-monitor.

Comment: Maybe edit your question to ask an actual question. Right now it's just two statements.

Comment: @popey the question is in the headline. I have edited the typos etc. 

let's try to stop stackoverflow from *remaining* such an ultra hostile place. WE should be ACCCEPTING of weird, partial, incomplete, content so long as it gets clicks and helps people. More of a search engine than a place to go read things.